# Can't boot into recovery mode - boot is stuck after selecting the option from GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, recovery-mode

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 14.04 into single user mode so that I can reset the root password.

I am doing the following steps:

- Reboot
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Select: `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`
- Select: `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)`
- Enter and wait .... it's 'booting'

Wait a really long time and it does not go anywhere. What can be the cause and how should I proceed?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 btw

Comment: You can upload your screenshots to https://www.imgur.com and copy the link to your question (you can [edit] it!). That's the same image hoster the site would also use for your pictures once you gained enough reputation. It just saves a few clicks for you and lets you display a preview ;-)

Comment: Have you tried another kernel entry?